# Pause journeys for more than 14 days

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

The documentation says that 14 days is the maximum time you can pause a journey. Looking at the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/JourneyPauseByDefinitionKey.htm), I see the parameter `PausedDays`.

I am thinking of testing this with `"PausedDays":15`,
for example.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? Well the call would be successful and it would pause the journey, but it would only pause it for 1 day.  So although it would be successful call - you would not successfully pause for more than 14 days via the API.

Even if this were to work, it would not be recommended as the Triggered Send queue (aka Journey Builder Send queue) will only hold records for 14 days before they start falling off the queue and disappear into the nether.

This is very bad as not only are they not emailed, but they are added into the SFMC TSD DE associated with that send, and are recognized in the Journey as having been sent to as they hit that Activity - despite nothing going out for them. This can really muck up your analytics and reporting.

There currently is not really a way to accomplish this even if you do not have JB Email Send Activities inside of the Journey as the max is 14 overall. I am unaware of any hacks or processes to get beyond this limitation.